# when was the last time Ansi_warning was set

Tags: sql-server

In our production database there is an sp which was working fine till 2nd Nov 2014 and suddenly it started giving warnings that is
 Warning : Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation because we Ansi_warning ON in our Production database 
so to resolve it we had marked as set Ansi_warning OFF in the beginning sp

So can anybody tell me is there any way I can check when was the last time or by whom  Ansi_warning was set

Answer (score 0):

You can see all your configuration changes by using this t-sql

```
DECLARE @sTracePath VARCHAR(1024)

SELECT @sTracePath=CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),value) FROM fn_trace_getinfo(DEFAULT) 
WHERE property=2

SELECT TEXTData,HostName,ApplicationName,DatabaseName,LoginName,SPID,StartTime,EventSequence
FROM fn_trace_gettable(@sTracePath,1) 
WHERE TEXTData LIKE '%configure%' AND SPID<>@@spid
ORDER BY StartTime DESC
```

This of cource is based on that you have default trace enabled on the server.